# centos python2.7, ImportError: No module named _tkinter

Tags: python

centos python2.7,when I import Tkinter, it shows "import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk ImportError: No module named _tkinter",and I find out many solutions( like installing tcl-devel,tk-devel and so on), but they cannot tackle this problem, how I DEAL WITH it? but oddly, it is right with  "import tkinter as tk" .

Comment: `import tkinter` ??

Comment: yes, it can import tkinter in python2.7

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install python python-tk idle python-pmw python-imaging`

Comment: apt-get : command not found. it has no apt-get

Comment: on your linux terminal

Comment: yes, but it still no use

Comment: install this http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/25204049/dir/centos_6/com/python27-tkinter-2.7.5-7.el6.centos.alt.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: but how to install it? thank you